# How to call getItem() & getOptionList()in an Observer.php - Magento

Tags: php, magento, observers

I have an observer (checkout_cart_product_add_after) and would like to get the selected custom options array.

I have found the two elements I require in:

```
app/design/frontend/MY-THEME/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Which are:

```
1. $_item = $this->getItem();
2. $_options = $this->getOptionList();
```

I just don't know how to get them in an observer i.e. what else I have to call.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

please go to the following url

```html
http://inchoo.net/magento/updating-options-of-configurable-product-that-is-already-in-the-cart/
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Observers always start returning data from their respective "events".

So in your case you have to first get checkout-quote object in your observer's function code using below line:

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
```

Then you can get custom options for each item in items collection from the quote like below:

```
$quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');
foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $options = $helper->getCustomOptions($item);
    //do anything with $options.
}
```

Try this. hope it helps.

Also have you already referred below links ?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16804/get-the-object-of-the-whole-quotation-in-observer

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63752/get-products-final-price-with-its-selected-custom-option-on-add-to-cart

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-get-selected-custom-options-on-onepage